# botframework hosted in AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have been trying to deploy my botframework bot in to AWS API Gateway. I am using the **aws serverless express** framework to host this application.

The only thing I can find is this conversation which gives some good ideas on how to get this working.

https://gitter.im/Microsoft/BotBuilder?at=57832060bdafd191075d92b3

The suggestion from the above was to pass to the request to listener function which work well

```
{ body:{}, headers: {} }
```

and use the following for the response where end can be a no-op.

```
{ status: function (code) {}, end: () {} }
```

My code that runs but doesn't receive a response from the bot is this.

```
var connectorListener = connector.listen();
function listen() {
    return function (req, res) {

        var response = res;
        connectorListener(req, { status: (code) => { response.status(code); }, end: () => { response.end(););
    }
 }
```

If I remove res.end() and leave as a no op as suggested I get a response back from the chatbot in 1-2 seconds, but it also makes the lambda run for 30 seconds which is the timeout for API Gateway.

Is there a way to make this work so I can receive messages back without making the lambda timeout?